# Whats the difference between spring-framework-bom and platform-bom?

Tags: spring, maven

Ive been experimenting with Spring BOM and note there are two build managers - spring-framework-bom and platform-bom

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId> 
                <version>${spring.version}</version> 
                <type>pom</type> 
                <scope>import</scope> 
            </dependency> 
        </dependencies> 
</dependencyManagement>
```

Or

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Whats the difference? Or has spring-framework-bom been superceded? Personally I prefer the spring-framework-bom approach as i can control the spring version?

Comment: The spring-framework-bom is only for the spring-framework. The io.spring.platform contains a lot more (most of the spring portfolio projects) in versions that are tested together and work together. You can still control the spring version, use the io.spring.platform as a parent and add a `spring.version` property.

Comment: I have usually seen BOM (bill of materials) used with dependencyManagement tag which wraps the entire dependences tag.

Comment: M. Deinum how would i specify the spring.version? I had a check online and cant see any example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hunt around on this question last week, and as M Deinum has stated the difference is that spring-framework-bom is just for the framework. I then raised an issue that how can i control the spring version if using platform-bom.

The answer is to check the spring boot dependencies project for spring version -

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

A summary of versions are -

Spring Platform BOM Version Spring Version
1.1.2.RELEASE               4.2.0.RC1
1.1.0.RELEASE               4.1.3.RELEASE
1.0.0.RELEASE               4.0.5.RELEASE

Reference -

https://glenware.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/spring-bom-bill-of-materials/

Comment: The GitHub link is dead.

Comment: Spring Boot Dependencies POM on GitHub: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml